# How to set values to local Storage/ session storage in webView running typescript in Android?

Tags: android, typescript, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I am trying to set values in localStorage / sessionStorage for webview which is running on the typescript.

Step 1->
I have set the following properties for webview

```
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView.settings.databaseEnabled = true
    webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
```

Step 2->
I am  setting values in storage with the help of the following script

```js
val mimeType = "text/html"
val encoding = "utf-8"

val injection = "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
  "sessionStorage.setItem('" + key + "',  '" + val1 + "');" +
  "sessionStorage.setItem('" + key2 + "', '" + val2 + "');" +
  "sessionStorage.setItem('" + key3 + "', '" + val3 + "');" +
  "sessionStorage.setItem('" + key4 + "', '" + val4 + "');" +
  "localStorage.setItem('" + key5 + "', '" + val5 + "');" +
  "localStorage.setItem('" + key6 + "', '" + val6 + "');" +
  "console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN'))" +
  "window.location.replace('**webview_url**');" +
  "</script>"



webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
  "**webview_url**",
  injection,
  mimeType,
  encoding,
  ""
)
```

I am able to access the saved value in storage with the following code. So it seems that values are saved in storage.

"console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN'))"

**But once the webview is loaded , it loads the blank webview.**
Also, I have provided the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and set android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Any suggestions for this problem?